# android listview notifyDataSetChanged refresh all item .

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

My listview will show a list of photos from internet , and there is a addMore button on bottom of listview , when i click the addMore button , the activity will load more picture from internet , and add to the list , and call notifyDataSetChanged of the listview to refresh the data. it works , but i see the last loaded photo will has a bling . i see , the getView of the adapter be call for all photos on the screen , but this is not i want , i just want the new photos be added to the screen .

thanks for help !

Comment: call listview.requestLayout(); youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you mean Lazy Loading the photos ? i think it will not work . case it will call the getView also .

Answer (score 1):

You can't say Adapter to refresh only one item. You should just make getView() function as quick as possible to prevent redraw issues.